# Why is the event RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs launched before I finished loading the progress bar in its entirety?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, progress-bar, backgroundworker

When I'm running a heavy task or a few data, at the end of the task the `label` showing the percentage reaches 100% correctly and displays the `finalized message`, but even the `progressBar` has not loaded in its entirety, when the completion message is displayed you can see the animation of the progress bar that completes your work.

I have not been able to solve this problem, and the natural way that a progress bar should work as in all the systems that I have seen, the progress is completed and then show a finished message.

---

Here I leave an example:

```
BackgroundWorker bg = new BackgroundWorker();

private void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bg.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    bg.ProgressChanged += bg_ProgressChanged;
    bg.DoWork += bg_DoWork;
    bg.RunWorkerCompleted += bg_RunWorkerCompleted;
    bg.RunWorkerAsync();
    label1.Visible = true;
    progressBar1.Visible = true;
}
```

Dowork Event:

```
private void bg_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int progress = 0, percent = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++) //Cycle that will represent the heavy task
    {
        totalRecords = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; 

        progress++;
        percent = Convert.ToInt16((((double)progress / (double)totalRecords ) * 100.00)); 
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        bg.ReportProgress(percent );
    }
}
```

ProgressChanged

```
private void bg_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Change the value of the ProgressBar to the BackgroundWorker progress.
    progressBar1.Step = 1;
    progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
    progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
    progressBar1.Maximum = 100;

    if (e.ProgressPercentage > 100)
    {
        label1.Text = "100%";
        progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Maximum;
    }
    else
    {
        label1.Text = Convert.ToString(e.ProgressPercentage) + "%";
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
}
```

Finally, the `RunWorkerCompleted` event that is executed when the BackgroundWorker has finished:

```
private void bg_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Done...");
    label1.Visible = false;
    progressBar1.Visible = false;
}
```

---

**How can I solve this progress bar animation problem?**

**Environment:** Visual Studio 2010 (WindowsForms) & .NET NetFramework 4.

Comment: ProgressBar animates its progress, that produces about a 1 second lag.  So you are hiding it too soon to ever see it reach 100%.  That the native Windows control does not allow disabling this animation is a considerable design flaw.  You can get to 99% by forcing it to move backwards, that is not animated.

Comment: How can i solve it? The truth I have no idea I've tried several things and do not work :( , the `Thread.Sleep` I've placed so you can appreciate the animation

Comment: Couldn't reproduce, even with your code as-is (expect for the table count, replaced with a static number). In my test, the MessageBox appears properly after the bar is full and the label displays 100%.

Comment: If you want Thread.Sleep() to do anything useful then you have to put it *after* the ReportProgress() call.  Putting it inside the loop is not so useful, that just slows everything down a lot.

Comment: @Kilazur You should observe carefully the label if it reaches 100% before displaying the message, but the progress bar is missing a bit to finish, try placing a fixed number lower as 80 or 100 etc.

Comment: @J.Rodríguez I used the number 10, actually. I can clearly see every step of progression. That being said, I'm on Windows Server 2008 R2, so I have the most basic, Windows XP like graphical interface; maybe your issue is linked to a delay in the animation of progress bars in Vista+ GUI?

Comment: @HansPassant So the order should be like this: `bg.ReportProgress(percent );` and `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);` ?

Comment: @Kilazur I'm on Windows 10

Comment: I have no idea why you can't see that make a difference.  Did you try?  Another silly hack is to set the ProgressBar.Maximum to 10000 instead of 100.  Then update it twice with value = progress * 100 and value = progress * 100 - 1.  Moving it backwards is not animated.

Comment: @HansPassant I haven't tried it like that, I'm going to try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're facing a classic problem of Windows' Aero animations.
*Informations extracted from [this page](https://derekwill.com/2014/06/24/combating-the-lag-of-the-winforms-progressbar/).*

This lag happens when a progress bar is incremented. But it doesn't happen when the progress bar is **decremented**.

So basically, what you want to do is move **past** the actual value you should get to, then decrement to the actual value.

The author of the page uses an extension method, feel free to do as well; I'm just putting the relevant code here:

```
// To get around the progressive animation, we need to move the 
// progress bar backwards.
if (value == pb.Maximum)
{
    // Special case as value can't be set greater than Maximum.
    pb.Maximum = value + 1;     // Temporarily increase Maximum
    pb.Value = value + 1;       // Move past
    pb.Maximum = value;         // Reset maximum
}
else
{
    pb.Value = value + 1;       // Move past
}
pb.Value = value;
```

Comment: How can I use the extension method without having to create a class? `public static class ExtensionMethods` `public static void SetProgressNoAnimation (this ProgressBar pb, int value)`

Comment: You can't, but you don't have to. You can just use the code I put in my answer.

Comment: Ready! Thank you very much the problem is solved, you saved my life!